# How to change a uint8Array to Buffer in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

Any alternative to Buffer.from() in Javascript for Dart ?

I want to change the unit8Array / HexString to Buffer in Dart

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link with the methods you can use:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-typed_data/ByteBuffer-class.html
You can use the asUint8List() method or vice versa using hascode() method which would return you the int array.
Do comment if it helps !
Might be helpful :)